# Open local files in Firefox without the "file:///" OR teat / as \

Tags: firefox, local

I am looking for a tweak, addon or a fix to let me open local uri or urls without the file:/// prefix (like in IE or Chrome)

Example:

```
c:/folder/file.txt
```

It works if I change the forward slash to backslash, but it I need it like the example, or a fix to treat both slashes the same in Firefox.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need it for viewing some links of local pages, that are not linked through any files

Comment: So, you have some links that can be reached with Windows-style paths ("C:\foo"), but not URI-style paths ("file:///c:/foo")?

Comment: You want an ugly hack so that Firefox will accept syntactically invalid URLs... I would encourage you to fix the broken links in the local pages instead. Surely that will be better and more compatible all-around.

Comment: Could you make a simple webserver (nodejs, Go or whatever) that serves C:\ from / on localhost?

Comment: I just need to copy and past such url in the browser (Firefox), and it opens normally as IE or Chrome – Mike 1 hour ago